# MAMP localhost wordpress site, not possible to sign in, username and password are correct

Tags: login, localhost

I have two sites on my localhost server. The other one has a problem when trying to sign in. The username and password are correct,  I can access the PHP my admin and check them from there,  so I know they are correct. I even changed the password from there but the new password has the same problem.

The site appears on the browser but when trying to login the error message is "The password you entered for the username is incorrect."

I have cleared cookies and cache. It doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The password uses an MD5 hash, enter your password into a MD5 hasher and paste that into your database. Just pasting in text to the user table will not work.

Also, check the box to stay logged in. It helps sometimes when the cookies don't get set properly.

Finally, just try the "Reset Password," it is the easiest way to go.